# Magento 2 creating product attributes through CSV import

Tags: magento-2.1, product-attribute, importexport, magento-2.1.4

I need to create a module that can create custom product attributes as per the csv provided. I need it to import CSV via Magento 2 default csv import and validator.

I know that we need two table `eav_attribute` and `catalog_eav_attribute` table for this.

now the problem is how to validate the csv for both the table simultaneously.Anyone who has done it or have done it already please suggest me the correct way.